# Updating one row in a listView, updating every fourth row

Tags: java, android, listview

I would like to update a single listview item and it works fine until I scroll down to items that are not visible and seems that there is an item (which was not visible) getting updated as well (I see this when I scroll down)

[image]

The image above describes the issue, when i update listview item in position 0, the item in position 5 (not visible until i scroll) also updates (it should not) and if i do the same for pos 1 then pos 6 is also updated and so on and so on even vice-versa, eg: when i update pos 7 and scroll up pos 2 will be updated as well, how can I prevent this and only have the listview update the item that i click on (and not update the listview item which is not visible until scroll)?

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int correctAnswers;
    private int incorrectAnswers;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        correctAnswers = 0;
        incorrectAnswers = 0;

        try{
            DingDongDatabaseHelper coffeinaDatabaseHelper = new DingDongDatabaseHelper(this);
            db = coffeinaDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            cursor = db.query("BPIE", new String[]{"_id", "QUESTION", "ANSWER1", "ANSWER2", "ANSWER3", "ANSWER4", "CORRECT"},null, null, null, null,null);
            Random rand = new Random();
            CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.test_adapter, cursor, new String[]{ "QUESTION", "ANSWER1", "ANSWER2", "ANSWER3", "ANSWER4"}, new int[]{R.id.text_test_question, R.id.radio_answer1, R.id.radio_answer2, R.id.radio_answer3, R.id.radio_answer4}, 0);

            }

            setListAdapter(listAdapter);


        }catch(SQLException e){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Błąd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View item, int position, long id) {

        RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer1);
        RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer2);
        RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer3);
        RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer4);
        radio1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        radio2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        radio3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        radio4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        String correctAnswer="";
        String selectedAnswer="";
        if(item != null){
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
            RadioButton selectedButton = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            if(selectedButton!=null){
                if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                    correctAnswer = cursor.getString(6);
                }
                    selectedAnswer = String.valueOf(selectedButton.getText());


                    if(correctAnswer.equals(selectedAnswer)){
                        selectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        correctAnswers++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        incorrectAnswers++;
                        selectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        if(correctAnswer.equals(radio1.getText()))radio1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio2.getText()))radio2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio3.getText()))radio3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio4.getText()))radio4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    }

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "CORRECT: " + correctAnswer + "\nSELECTED: " + selectedAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post `SimpleCursorAdapter` code

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter This is build-in class

Comment: This happens probably because some views are reused automatically and their states are retained. To control the behavior of the reused views, I guess you will need to set a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to your adapter. In the SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder, you will want to describe the behavior for each view you need to control.

Comment: You should have to use Custom CusrorAdapter

Comment: Could you help me make this Custim CursorAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

AnsweredQuestion.java:

```
public class AnsweredQuestion {
int selectedAnswerViewId;
int correctAnswerViewId;

public AnsweredQuestion(int selectedAnswerViewId, int correctAnswerViewId) {
    this.selectedAnswerViewId = selectedAnswerViewId;
    this.correctAnswerViewId = correctAnswerViewId;
}
}
```

TestActivity.java:

```
public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;
private int correctAnswers;
private int incorrectAnswers;

private ArrayList<Integer> answeredQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<Integer, AnsweredQuestion> answeredQuestionHashMap = new HashMap<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    correctAnswers = 0;
    incorrectAnswers = 0;

    try{
        DingDongDatabaseHelper coffeinaDatabaseHelper = new DingDongDatabaseHelper(this);
        db = coffeinaDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("BPIE", new String[]{"_id", "QUESTION", "ANSWER1", "ANSWER2", "ANSWER3", "ANSWER4", "CORRECT"},null, null, null, null,null);
        Random rand = new Random();
        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.test_adapter, cursor, new String[]{ "QUESTION", "ANSWER1", "ANSWER2", "ANSWER3", "ANSWER4"}, new int[]{R.id.text_test_question, R.id.radio_answer1, R.id.radio_answer2, R.id.radio_answer3, R.id.radio_answer4}, 0){
            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                int position = cursor.getPosition();
                RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer1);
                RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer2);
                RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer3);
                RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer4);
                radio1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                radio2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                radio3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                radio4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                if(answeredQuestions.contains(position)){
                    AnsweredQuestion answeredQuestion = answeredQuestionHashMap.get(position);
                    RadioButton selectedAnswer = view.findViewById(answeredQuestion.selectedAnswerViewId);
                    RadioButton correctAnswer = view.findViewById(answeredQuestion.correctAnswerViewId);
                    selectedAnswer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    correctAnswer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        };

        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }catch(SQLException e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Błąd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View item, int position, long id) {

    RadioButton radio1 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer1);
    RadioButton radio2 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer2);
    RadioButton radio3 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer3);
    RadioButton radio4 = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_answer4);
    radio1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    radio2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    radio3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    radio4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    String correctAnswer="";
    String selectedAnswer="";
    if(item != null){
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)item.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        RadioButton selectedButton = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        RadioButton correctButton = null;

        if(selectedButton!=null){
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                correctAnswer = cursor.getString(6);
            }
            selectedAnswer = String.valueOf(selectedButton.getText());

            if(correctAnswer.equals(selectedAnswer)){
                selectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                correctAnswers++;
                correctButton = selectedButton;
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectAnswers++;
                selectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                if(correctAnswer.equals(radio1.getText())) correctButton = radio1;
                else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio2.getText())) correctButton = radio2;
                else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio3.getText())) correctButton = radio3;
                else if(correctAnswer.equals(radio4.getText())) correctButton = radio4;
                correctButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "CORRECT: " + correctAnswer + "\nSELECTED: " + selectedAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

            if(!answeredQuestions.contains(position)) answeredQuestions.add(position);
            AnsweredQuestion answeredQuestion = new AnsweredQuestion(selectedButton.getId(), correctButton.getId());
            answeredQuestionHashMap.put(position, answeredQuestion);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope that helps!